# How do I connect to mysql server with Go and go-sql-driver?

Tags: mysql, go

I am following the tutorials [here](http://mwholt.blogspot.com/2013/05/writing-go-golang-web-app-with-nginx.html) and [here](http://goseeds.blogspot.com/2012/05/google-go-and-mysql-tutorial.html) but I am unable to connect to the `test` database that came with  mySQL installation. I can connect to mySql through the command line. What am I missing? When I run the code below I get the error "cannot ping":

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "/test")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("cannot ping")
        return
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, substitute your MySQL user name and password for the words `user` and `password`,

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@/test")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer db.Close()
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Ping")
}
```

Output:

```
Ping
```

Comment: Thanks for adding `err` in `fmt.Println(err)`. I was not seeing what errors I was getting.